# How to use datetime objects to get stock data through the yfinance api in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, finance, yfinance

I was trying to get data for stocks through the yfinance api in Python using Jupyter Notebooks. However when I use datetime objects in the "start" and "end" parameters of the function, I get an error. How do I fix this [This is the error I'm receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjKNr.png)

I tried to get stock data in the form of a dataframe through the download method of the yfinance api. However it gives me an error when I use datetime objects in the "start" and "end" parameters. I also tried to convert the datetime objects to timestamps to see if that would work but I received the same error.[This is the error I receive when I try using Timestamps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIhzw.png)

Comment: Post code, not screenshots.

Comment: You may need to update the pandas library to a newer version.

Comment: @8349697
 Thanks, I reinstalled Anaconda 3 and now it works